# Gmail doesn't thread replies from a contact

Tags: gmail

My Gmail's conversation view generally threads correctly, but replies from one of my contacts (Faith in this screenshot) create new threads. I thought part of it might be the `Re:` that gets added to the subject line, but even emails with the same subject (the top two) aren't threaded. I haven't asked Faith what their email client and settings are yet, but is there something I can do on my end or suggest that they do to ensure their replies thread?

[image]

Here are headers from a few emails:

- [Threaded 1](https://gist.github.com/MaxGhenis/7b748a2cb4aa65e9ef3b2141e0e6c84a)
- [Threaded 2](https://gist.github.com/MaxGhenis/0dd34c186f001a0268b96e65c5d44195)
- [Orphaned](https://gist.github.com/MaxGhenis/dd7642a4dec6ef927ff7aae02fb61c7c)

Comment: Can you drop the email header (redacting private info) in your question of 2 emails from this contact? Email header info is on the "Show Original" page under the 3 dots menu of the specific email in Gmail.

Comment: @CraigLambie this? https://gist.github.com/MaxGhenis/dd7642a4dec6ef927ff7aae02fb61c7c

Comment: Max I have put your header example into the question, as per @blind-spots, please add some others and header them accordingly so we can understand the issue better

Comment: Here are headers from two threaded emails: https://gist.github.com/MaxGhenis/7b748a2cb4aa65e9ef3b2141e0e6c84a and https://gist.github.com/MaxGhenis/0dd34c186f001a0268b96e65c5d44195

Comment: Are you still having this problem?
If so, please check the to and from email addresses in the threaded and orphaned emails. You redacted them in the orphan, so I cannot check if they are exactly the same. The domain is there in the threaded ones, but you removed both in the main orphaned one.

Comment: Just re-reading the question. It might be something to do with Faith's email address, or domain changing or similar.
Can you check the From email address of Faith in the header of all 3 threads?